# How to run SAS programs sequentially in UNIX korn shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sas

Ok, there seems a lot of answers how to, but none worked out for me.
Here is my code.

'contents of my shell script starts here

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#. ~/.profile

#execute the file 
nohup sas /sas/cod1.sas -log /sas/logs/code1+%Y%m%d`.log 

wait

nohup sas /sas/code2.sas -log /sas/logs/code2.log 

#email the log
mailx -s " job1 is complete" name@domain.com < /sas/logs/code1+%Y%m%d`.log

wait

mailx -s " job2 is complete" name@domain.com < /sas/logs/code2.log
```

I was expecting that with the wait command it would first complete sasname1.sas and then proceed to sasname2.sas. However, this is not the case. I tried even withouth & sign, but with no luck. I am getting back to batch submitting in SAS and I recall it used to work, but I have no idea why it is not working any longer.  Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Are your missing back tick characters due to copy and pasting into markdown editor ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `nohup`ing just the script?
Are you missing `date`  in front of `+` ?

`code_runner.sh
---------------`

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#. ~/.profile

sas /sas/code1.sas                        -log /sas/logs/code1_`date +%Y%m%d`.log 
mailx -s " job1 is complete" name@domain.com < /sas/logs/code1_`date +%Y%m%d`.log

sas /sas/code2.sas                        -log /sas/logs/code2.log 
mailx -s " job2 is complete" name@domain.com < /sas/logs/code2.log
```

Issue command

```
nohup code_runner.sh
```